# Formhandler Multiple Forms on one page

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm stuck with formhandler on creating multiple forms on one page. What I've done so far is the following Code in my Setup Variables

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings {

  debug = 0
  formValuesPrefix = formhandler

    singleErrorTemplate {
    totalWrap = <div class="error">|</div>
    singleWrap = <span class="message">|</span>
  }
  preProcessors {
    1.class = Tx_Formhandler_PreProcessor_LoadDefaultValues
    1 {
      config.1 {
         name.defaultValue = Name
         email.defaultValue = E-Mail
      }
    }
  }
  validators {
    1.class = Validator_Default
    1.config.fieldConf {
      name {
        errorCheck.1 = required
      }
      email {
        errorCheck.1 = required
        errorCheck.2 = email
      }
    }
  }
  singleErrorTemplate {
    totalWrap = <div class="error">|</div>
    singleWrap = <span class="message">|</span>
  }
  finishers {

    # Finisher_Mail sends emails to an admin and/or the user.
    1.class = Finisher_Mail

    # Finisher_Redirect will redirect the user to another page after the form was submitted successfully.
    5.class = Finisher_Redirect
    5.config {
      redirectPage = {$formhandlerExamples.basic.contact-form.redirectPage}
    }
  }
}
```

But now I want to add a second form to my site. If I simply add a second plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings {} with a new formValuesPrefix it is not working. I am only getting a "Caught exception: Template not found" error.

When I remove the first form and the first settings, my form is working.

I could use a tutorial or something on how to add multiple forms with formhandler on one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured that out. What you need to do is, work with settings.predef instead of standard settings. For example

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings.predef.formhandler {
  # This name appears in the dropdown selector in plugin record
  name = Newsletter Contact
  debug = 0
  formValuesPrefix = formhandler

  singleErrorTemplate {
    totalWrap = <div class="error">|</div>
    singleWrap = <span class="message">|</span>
  }
  validators {
    1.class = Validator_Default
    1.config.fieldConf {
      name {
        errorCheck.1 = required
      }
      email {
        errorCheck.1 = required
        errorCheck.2 = email
      }
    }
  }
  singleErrorTemplate {
    totalWrap = <div class="error">|</div>
    singleWrap = <span class="message">|</span>
  }
  finishers {

    # Finisher_Mail sends emails to an admin and/or the user.
    1.class = Finisher_Mail

    # Finisher_Redirect will redirect the user to another page after the form was submitted successfully.
    5.class = Finisher_Redirect
    5.config {
      redirectPage = 8
    }
  }
}
```

Now you will find in your module this setting in a dropdown. If you create more of those, you'll have more settings to select. And every Form needs it's own setting.predef.